Iterate through Columns
I have an array that contains the months of the year and I want to extract a numerical value for a given month. For example, if the month is March it should return 3 (which I was able to achieve by specifying an individual index within the array).
I want to do the same however I want to setup a for loop that iterates through the columns of each cell and returns a numerical value for all 12 months. Currently, I am getting an error that states,

The parameters (number[],String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.

How can I resolve this? A portion of my code is below.
function allData_Price_2020(sheet1, sheet2) {
  var data1 = sheet1.getRange("B:D").getValues(); // Get all PNs, CCs, LCs 
  var data2 = sheet2.getRange("A:A").getValues(); // Get concatenated PNs, CCs, LCs 
  var data3 = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues(); // Get all data from tab
  var data4 = sheet1.getRange(4, 93, 1, 12).getValues(); // Get months from Price Table in tab

  for (var i = 4; i < data1.length; i++) { // Start iteration on row 5
    for (var j = 1; j < data4[0].length; j++) {
      // Extracts the month from date timestamp
      var month = Utilities.formatDate(data4, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM");

      // Rest of the code is irrelevant
    }
  }
}


There are 2 mistakes in your script.  First, data4 is defined twice, in the main body and in the for loop.  I prefer to use let instead of var  Second data4 is an array of values.  The first parameter to formatDate should be a Date object, not an array.

I was able to get my desired result by replacing "data4" in the "month" variable" with "data4[0][j]"

Since I accomplished that, is it possible for me to replace the original array with the numerical values? The current array contains timestamps of each month, I want my code to recognize them as numerical values.

This needs input data sample, expected output and a working code set to reproduce this - perhaps best as a working snippet using the <> snippet button as you edit.

A Date object already contains a number from which you can get month, day, year, time.  Look at Date

The following line assigns as array of arrays that might contain strings, numbers, booleans and Date objects:
var data4 = sheet1.getRange(4, 93, 1, 12).getValues();

The code is passing the whole array of arrays as the first parameter, instead of passing a Date Object
var month = Utilities.formatDate(data4,Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM"); // Extracts the month from date timestamp


Without having a sample of the data, it is unclear what should be the fix, but you might try replacing something of the form data4[rowIndex][columnIndex], where rowIndex is 0 based index to identify the row, and columnIndex is a 0 based index to identify the column. You should ensure that this returns a Date Object, otherwise you will get a similar error.
